# Calling function of $.fn.function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is the following.
Theres is a function custom jquery function with another function inside, f.e.:

```
$.fn.slides = function(args){

 function foo(args){

  }

}
```

My question is now: How can I call the method foo.

Comment: From outside the plugin? You can't. You'd have to expose the function one way or another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo` is not a method. It is a local function. There is no way to access it from outside the function in which it is defined unless you modify that function to expose it.

For example (and I *do not* recommend creating globals, you should probably attach the function to some other object):

```
$.fn.slides = function(args){
   function foo(args){ }
   window.foo = foo;
}
```

Comment: And then I can simply access it by call foo()?

Comment: Yes (assuming it doesn't depend on the context being a jQuery object … which raises the question of why it was being written as a jQuery plug-in in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

You can't call it from outside the function, unless you return an object which has `foo` attached to it, something like this:

```
$.fn.slides = function(args){

    this.foo = function (args){

    }

    return this;
}

$('blah').slides(args).foo(args);
```

Inside the function you can use it as a regular function:

```
$.fn.slides = function(args) {

    function foo(args) {

    }

    foo(args);
}
```

Comment: `$('blah').slides.foo(args);` is incorrect though. `foo` is not a property of `$.fn.slides`. *edit:* yep, that's better :)