# JavaScript "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html

Any idea why this is happening?
The Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: initMap.addMarker is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Map.html?_ijt=k803v4m45uoctft4qso4948sma:148)
```

The code (the important bits):

```
<script>
    // Initialize and add the map

    function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 41.9973, lng: 21.4280};
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 14, center: uluru});
        // The marker, positioned at Uluru
        // var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});

        function addMarker(props){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:props.coords,
                map:map
                //icon:props.iconImage

            });

            // Check for customicon
            if(props.iconImage){
                // Set icon image
                marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
            }


            // Check content
            if(props.content){
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content:props.content
                });


            }
        }
    }
</script>
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<!--The div element for the map -->
<div id="map"></div>
<button onclick="initMap.addMarker({ coords:{lat:Lat,lng:Long}, content:'<h1>bla bla content</h1>'})">Stavi Marker</button>
```

I get the error when i click on the button that is suppose to call the nested function addMarker. Thanks!

Comment: `initMap` does not return something that has `addMarker` on it.  `initMap` does not return anything at all.

Comment: `addMarker` is local to `initMap` (just like `uluru` and `map`), you can't access it outside of `initMap`, which is a function, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addMarker is not accessible. You'll need to add the method to the initMap function. Here is a small example:

```
function initMap()
{
    function addMarker(props){
        console.log(props);
    }

    initMap.addMarker = addMarker;
}

initMap()
initMap.addMarker('works')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like any code outside of the initMap() function does not have access to the addMarker function(). I recommend looking at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) site, a bit down at the section 'nested functions and closure'. I think to access it, you'll need to do `initMap().addMarker({...})` or `fn_addMarker({...})` (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657858/calling-function-of-fn-function))